# Why do we need dev branch?

Tags: git

I see some people use branch named `dev` beside `master` for development environment. Even they use feature branch, they say that having `dev` branch is better. I actually didn't hear suitable answer of why. Even there is dev branch, works must still be done before pushing it. (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

I really don't understand. Why do I need to have dev branch after all.

- I am using master branch as my development branch.
- Any of my undone works are in feature branches. Whenever I have done with a work in feature branch, I merge it into master.
- Any time I need to release, I am tagging master.
- If I have test, staging or preprod environments, I also have those branches.

Thats all. This flow fixes everything for me. I don't see any reason to have `dev` branch.

What case do I miss? What is the problem with using `master` as a development environment? Which cases you use dev branch for if you do?

Comment: Master works just fine for my team and me!

Comment: Thats all fine. I think it is followed as convention or they are cautious if they mess up something in their master branch.

Comment: dev branch may be useful when there are several teams on the same project, but it's not mandatory at all, it must fit your needs.

Comment: Git allows you to have whatever branch structure you want. If your workflow works for you, it's the right one to use. That is the beauty of git. You should probably ask the people using a dev branch why they do it. It probably works for them for some reason.

Comment: that depends. If master represents the state of your production environment it is useful to have a dev branch. Then you can always create a new branch based on what is run on production. But there are several working modes: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ and https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows have some nice explanations. Choose the one that applies to what you want to do.

Comment: @MadPhysicist , I am actually asking it right here. It is said that using dev is safer but I don't think so. I think having dev branch is about doing something wrong. Pushing undone and non-tested works cause this. I think feature branches are enough to be safe.I actually want to know, Do I think wrong?  Of course there are to many way for git flowing but what is ideal one.

Comment: @AhmetDAL what is "safer" is according to the workflow followed by the team (which may or may not include factors you aren't aware of). There is nothing intrinsically correct in saying one or the other is safer. The important thing is not what workflow decision has been made, but rather that it is consistently followed by all project contributors (in conjunction with things like automated build/testing that might follow the repo as well). There is no such thing as the "ideal" workflow generically speaking (which is why your question was closed as being primarily opinion based).

Comment: @mah I see that having dev branch is good for spesific bugfix or hotfix releases. The answer of question is YES we need. Its WHY we need to keep master at last release to release spesific bugfixes or hotfixes. Sometimes we can't have next release features with hotfix or bugfix of previous version. Keeping next release features in dev saves us. This is where dev branch is needed. There should be ideal one and this is it. Not being any trouble without dev branch does not mean it is the ideal one. Because one day you may meet the situation.

Comment: You can think of your master tags as separate branch pointers, so in this case there is no major reason to have another branch if you don't want one. Personally if I am working in a team I think branches are easier, since I don't need to worry about master commits after the latest tag - there is only one "true" version of master, and that is `HEAD`.

Comment: There is a good discussion here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312022/the-trend-of-the-develop-branch-going-away, that fewer people use dev branch nowadays, and specific workflows for a dev branch are described there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Master branch which is your a working branch of your production, it has to be bug free, well tested and contain stable code. Development branch however can contain issues and other complexities.

Let's say, you have committed your development from dev server on master branch, you pull on staging and unfortunately it creates issue w.r.t. staging server setup, you go back to development and fix it. In between this, client asks for urgent hotfix in which you want to push some changes urgently on live server. This reverting and changing files again can be a crazy tough job in such situations.

Instead, if you keep master branch only for live, dev branch for development environment, stage branch for testing and staging environment.

You develop on dev branch, push it to staging, if works merge it with staging branch, if not, go back to dev, fix it and then push again. If stage is all set, you pull that to live. Check for some time. If there are issues, immediately checkout to master, fix it, push stage again, Once all set, merge with master and checkout in master as current branch.

In this case, if client asks for urgent changes on live, you checkout to master branch on development server, create a new branch from it (never change directly into master), fix it, push on stage and then push on live. In this hurry, if fix goes wrong, you can always checkout to master and if  correct merge it with  master.

In this case, your dev branch on development server is untouched which is easier to commence your development again.

Comment: Git doesn't care if your master branch is bug free, or tested, or stable. There's nothing wrong with your opinions but I hope you realize the question asked is problematic because there is _no_ correct answer in general... it's pure opinion (be it an individual's, or that of a team collective)... whatever works best fort any given team is the right answer for that team.

Comment: Yes even I agree, I just assumed master to be bug free as it was corresponding to production environment in my example.

Comment: Urgent bugfix or hotfix releases are the answer why we need a branch like dev beside master.

Answer (score 5):

I would advise that you use a dev branch.

I typically follow the following rule of thumb:

- Small changes in the code go on "development" branch.
- Major features that several people will be working on go on their own "feature" branch.
- Small bug fixes on the master branch go on their own branch called "hot fix" and are merged back in the master branch right away.

**Everything at the end gets merged into the master. Master should be considered your release branch that goes out to the public. It should be code that has been tested and is considered stable.**

Explained more in detail here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow